# Mono Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.HttpClient:.ctor (System.Net.Http.HttpClient): method body is empty

Tags: c#, mono, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to get my C# application to run on Mono. Its purpose is to consume as REST WebApi using System.Net.Http.HttpClient. However, when I run it, the Mono .Net runtime throws the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.HttpClient:.ctor (): method body is empty.
```

Here is the source code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject.Data
{     
    public class DataAccess
    {
        public string Uri;
        public int DeviceId;
        static HttpClient client;
        public DataAccess(string uri)
        {
            Uri = uri;            
            client = new HttpClient();            
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);    
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
        public async Task<List<Event>> GetEvents(int deviceId)
        {
            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("devices/{0}/events", deviceId));
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                events = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Event>>();
            }
            return events;
        }

        //... other data access methods
```

I am running on Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.2 (Debian 4.6.2.7+dfsg-1) on Raspbian distro.

Has anyone come across this ?

Thanks in advance.
Damien.

Comment: this sounds like the problem is in `HttpClient` itself - are you perhaps deploying the reference assembly? the reference assemblies are empty shells without implementation

Comment: I think you are correct. I found the correct assembly under the /packages folder. When I deployed that, the issue was no more.
Thanks.